# How to handle connection close in tornado

Tags: rabbitmq, tornado

I use PikaClient to connection to RabbitMQ in tornado, I change single client in RabbitMQ tornado demo to a client dict so I can deal with multiple user.

Now I use ajax to get new message every 5 seconds in the web page, it works, but after user close the connection in browser, the PikaClient connection does not get closed, RabbitMQ's socket descriptor number keep increasing every time a new request comes.

I need to close the pikaclient connection on connection close

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous 
def get(self): 
    uid = self.get_argument(“uid”, “0”) 
    self.uid = uid 
    if self.application.pika.has_key(uid): 
        pass
    else:
        self.application.pika[uid] = PikaClient(uuid=str(uid))
        self.application.pika[uid].connect()

    self.on_ajaxdone(uid)


def on_ajaxdone(self, uid): 
     if self.request.connection.stream.closed(): 
         return
    self.set_header("Content-type", "application/json")
    self.write(json.dumps(self.application.pika[uid].get_messages()))
    self.finish()

def on_connection_close(self):
    try: 
        self.application.pika[self.uid].connection.close()
    except: 
        pass
    finally: 
        self.application.pika.pop(self.uid)
```

but the code doesn't work, I change on_ajaxdone into add_timeout, when the timeout>2s, it seems to work

```
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(
        time.time() + 5,
        lambda: self.on_ajaxdone(uid))
```

Can I handle on_connection_close without any timeout ?

Comment: Any updates since our last post?
What if you changed the on_connection_close to on_finish. Is it ok you to close the `PikaClient` for every request?